# How Can I print Python output at runtime in PHP

Tags: php, python, python-2.7

I want to display the output of the python script at runtime on the web browser through php. Can someone help upon this..??

I'm calling a simple python script through php here is the code: 
**run.py:**

```
  import os
    import subprocess
    import sys
    import time
    print "<br> Hi from Python"
    sys.stdout.flush()
    for i in range(0,5):
        time.sleep(1)
        print "<br> Hi from Python"
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

this is the php script:

```
<?php
$handle = popen("python run.py ", 'r');
while(!feof($handle)) {
$buffer = fgets($handle);
echo "$buffer<br/>\n";
ob_flush();
}
pclose($handle);
?>
```

Can someone help upon this..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `exec` instead

```
$res = NULL;

exec("python full/path/to/script.py 2>&1" ,$res); //2>&1 @comments.KEK

if(isset($res)){
    foreach($res as $rowRes){
        echo $rowRes;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to append `2>&1` to redirect error output to your php script, like this: `exec("python full/path/to/script.py 2>&1" ,$res);`

Comment: No working..the output from python is all displayed at one go only, once it has completed processing..

Comment: You can't stream the output to the user, if you want to, use `WebSocket` or any other live streaming solution

Comment: Okay, Isn't there any other way??
Actually I just want what the python scripting is printing should come to web browser in real time